# NameError: name 'K' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm following the guide to Transformers and the colab project https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XBP0Zh8K4g_n0A2p1UlGFf3dij0EX_Kt

but when I run the cell with the line `multi_head = build_model()` I get the error.

this is the output from the console:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 multi_head = build_model()
>
> 5 frames  in (x)
>        40         self.dropout = Dropout(attn_dropout)
>        41     def **call**(self, q, k, v, mask):
>   ---> 42         attn = Lambda(lambda x:K.batch_dot(x[0],x[1],axes=[2,2])/self.temper)([q, k])
>        43         if mask is not None:
>        44             mmask = Lambda(lambda x:(-1e+10)*(1-x))(mask)
>
> NameError: name 'K' is not defined

It just runs after the model architecture code, which the error refers to.
Can you see where this `K`should be defined?

```
import random, os, sys
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import *
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import *
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Layer

try:
    from dataloader import TokenList, pad_to_longest
    # for transformer
except: pass



embed_size = 60

class LayerNormalization(Layer):
    def __init__(self, eps=1e-6, **kwargs):
        self.eps = eps
        super(LayerNormalization, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.gamma = self.add_weight(name='gamma', shape=input_shape[-1:],
                                     initializer=Ones(), trainable=True)
        self.beta = self.add_weight(name='beta', shape=input_shape[-1:],
                                    initializer=Zeros(), trainable=True)
        super(LayerNormalization, self).build(input_shape)
    def call(self, x):
        mean = K.mean(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        std = K.std(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        return self.gamma * (x - mean) / (std + self.eps) + self.beta
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

class ScaledDotProductAttention():
    def __init__(self, d_model, attn_dropout=0.1):
        self.temper = np.sqrt(d_model)
        self.dropout = Dropout(attn_dropout)
    def __call__(self, q, k, v, mask):
        attn = Lambda(lambda x:K.batch_dot(x[0],x[1],axes=[2,2])/self.temper)([q, k])
        if mask is not None:
            mmask = Lambda(lambda x:(-1e+10)*(1-x))(mask)
            attn = Add()([attn, mmask])
        attn = Activation('softmax')(attn)
        attn = self.dropout(attn)
        output = Lambda(lambda x:K.batch_dot(x[0], x[1]))([attn, v])
        return output, attn

class MultiHeadAttention():
    # mode 0 - big martixes, faster; mode 1 - more clear implementation
    def __init__(self, n_head, d_model, d_k, d_v, dropout, mode=0, use_norm=True):
        self.mode = mode
        self.n_head = n_head
        self.d_k = d_k
        self.d_v = d_v
        self.dropout = dropout
        if mode == 0:
            self.qs_layer = Dense(n_head*d_k, use_bias=False)
            self.ks_layer = Dense(n_head*d_k, use_bias=False)
            self.vs_layer = Dense(n_head*d_v, use_bias=False)
        elif mode == 1:
            self.qs_layers = []
            self.ks_layers = []
            self.vs_layers = []
            for _ in range(n_head):
                self.qs_layers.append(TimeDistributed(Dense(d_k, use_bias=False)))
                self.ks_layers.append(TimeDistributed(Dense(d_k, use_bias=False)))
                self.vs_layers.append(TimeDistributed(Dense(d_v, use_bias=False)))
        self.attention = ScaledDotProductAttention(d_model)
        self.layer_norm = LayerNormalization() if use_norm else None
        self.w_o = TimeDistributed(Dense(d_model))

    def __call__(self, q, k, v, mask=None):
        d_k, d_v = self.d_k, self.d_v
        n_head = self.n_head

        if self.mode == 0:
            qs = self.qs_layer(q)  # [batch_size, len_q, n_head*d_k]
            ks = self.ks_layer(k)
            vs = self.vs_layer(v)

            def reshape1(x):
                s = tf.shape(x)   # [batch_size, len_q, n_head * d_k]
                x = tf.reshape(x, [s[0], s[1], n_head, d_k])
                x = tf.transpose(x, [2, 0, 1, 3])  
                x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, s[1], d_k])  # [n_head * batch_size, len_q, d_k]
                return x
            qs = Lambda(reshape1)(qs)
            ks = Lambda(reshape1)(ks)
            vs = Lambda(reshape1)(vs)

            if mask is not None:
                mask = Lambda(lambda x:K.repeat_elements(x, n_head, 0))(mask)
            head, attn = self.attention(qs, ks, vs, mask=mask)  

            def reshape2(x):
                s = tf.shape(x)   # [n_head * batch_size, len_v, d_v]
                x = tf.reshape(x, [n_head, -1, s[1], s[2]]) 
                x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 2, 0, 3])
                x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, s[1], n_head*d_v])  # [batch_size, len_v, n_head * d_v]
                return x
            head = Lambda(reshape2)(head)
        elif self.mode == 1:
            heads = []; attns = []
            for i in range(n_head):
                qs = self.qs_layers[i](q)   
                ks = self.ks_layers[i](k) 
                vs = self.vs_layers[i](v) 
                head, attn = self.attention(qs, ks, vs, mask)
                heads.append(head); attns.append(attn)
            head = Concatenate()(heads) if n_head > 1 else heads[0]
            attn = Concatenate()(attns) if n_head > 1 else attns[0]

        outputs = self.w_o(head)
        outputs = Dropout(self.dropout)(outputs)
        if not self.layer_norm: return outputs, attn
        # outputs = Add()([outputs, q]) # sl: fix
        return self.layer_norm(outputs), attn

class PositionwiseFeedForward():
    def __init__(self, d_hid, d_inner_hid, dropout=0.1):
        self.w_1 = Conv1D(d_inner_hid, 1, activation='relu')
        self.w_2 = Conv1D(d_hid, 1)
        self.layer_norm = LayerNormalization()
        self.dropout = Dropout(dropout)
    def __call__(self, x):
        output = self.w_1(x) 
        output = self.w_2(output)
        output = self.dropout(output)
        output = Add()([output, x])
        return self.layer_norm(output)

class EncoderLayer():
    def __init__(self, d_model, d_inner_hid, n_head, d_k, d_v, dropout=0.1):
        self.self_att_layer = MultiHeadAttention(n_head, d_model, d_k, d_v, dropout=dropout)
        self.pos_ffn_layer  = PositionwiseFeedForward(d_model, d_inner_hid, dropout=dropout)
    def __call__(self, enc_input, mask=None):
        output, slf_attn = self.self_att_layer(enc_input, enc_input, enc_input, mask=mask)
        output = self.pos_ffn_layer(output)
        return output, slf_attn


def GetPosEncodingMatrix(max_len, d_emb):
    pos_enc = np.array([
        [pos / np.power(10000, 2 * (j // 2) / d_emb) for j in range(d_emb)] 
        if pos != 0 else np.zeros(d_emb) 
            for pos in range(max_len)
            ])
    pos_enc[1:, 0::2] = np.sin(pos_enc[1:, 0::2]) # dim 2i
    pos_enc[1:, 1::2] = np.cos(pos_enc[1:, 1::2]) # dim 2i+1
    return pos_enc

def GetPadMask(q, k):
    ones = K.expand_dims(K.ones_like(q, 'float32'), -1)
    mask = K.cast(K.expand_dims(K.not_equal(k, 0), 1), 'float32')
    mask = K.batch_dot(ones, mask, axes=[2,1])
    return mask

def GetSubMask(s):
    len_s = tf.shape(s)[1]
    bs = tf.shape(s)[:1]
    mask = K.cumsum(tf.eye(len_s, batch_shape=bs), 1)
    return mask

class Transformer():
    def __init__(self, len_limit, embedding_matrix, d_model=embed_size, \
              d_inner_hid=512, n_head=10, d_k=64, d_v=64, layers=2, dropout=0.1, \
              share_word_emb=False, **kwargs):
        self.name = 'Transformer'
        self.len_limit = len_limit
        self.src_loc_info = False # True # sl: fix later
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.decode_model = None
        d_emb = d_model

        pos_emb = Embedding(len_limit, d_emb, trainable=False, \
                            weights=[GetPosEncodingMatrix(len_limit, d_emb)])

        i_word_emb = Embedding(max_features, d_emb, weights=[embedding_matrix]) # Add Kaggle provided embedding here

        self.encoder = Encoder(d_model, d_inner_hid, n_head, d_k, d_v, layers, dropout, \
                               word_emb=i_word_emb, pos_emb=pos_emb)


    def get_pos_seq(self, x):
        mask = K.cast(K.not_equal(x, 0), 'int32')
        pos = K.cumsum(K.ones_like(x, 'int32'), 1)
        return pos * mask

    def compile(self, active_layers=999):
        src_seq_input = Input(shape=(None, ))
        x = Embedding(max_features, embed_size, weights=[embedding_matrix])(src_seq_input)

        # LSTM before attention layers
        x = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(x)
        x = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))(x) 

        x, slf_attn = MultiHeadAttention(n_head=3, d_model=300, d_k=64, d_v=64, dropout=0.1)(x, x, x)

        avg_pool = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
        max_pool = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
        conc = concatenate([avg_pool, max_pool])
        conc = Dense(64, activation="relu")(conc)
        x = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(conc)   


        self.model = Model(inputs=src_seq_input, outputs=x)
        self.model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 7):

If you look at where `K` is being used you will see:

`K.expand_dims
 K.cumsum
 K.batch_dot`

These are Keras backend functions. The code is missing a `from keras import backend as K`, which I think is a standard abbreviation.

Comment: Oh I see. Many Thanks! I'm very new to all this, I couldn't have recognised it for another x months haha